# What is the difference between ICallBackEventHandler and HTTPHandler?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, icallbackeventhandler

When we write our own custom HTTPHandlers aren't they behave the same way as ICallBackEventHanlder does? we use both to make ajax calls from our web page, isn't this correct? or my understanding wrong, I wont doubt if it is :(

Obviously HTTPHandlers are more broader concept since a web page (.aspx) etc are also http handlers.

Answer (score 0):

A ICallBackEventHandler is for integration with a page -- a handler is for anything. A callback handler is useful when you want to do an ajax request from the client-side of a page, and from that handler you still want access to all of the controls on the page, their re-saturated state that comes from ViewState, etc. An http handler has no access to the page or its state. A callback handler can also push some state changes back to the client. For example, a callback handler might render something which requires the __EVENTVALIDATION field on the client-side to be updated.